# Resume timer after countdown and specified break

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

The user hits start after specifying a break period and time period in minutes (whole numbers) and calling `timer`.

The `stopWatch` called by `timer` works (albeit stopping at .01 seconds, to be figured out later).

I'd like the user to be able to specify a break period, after which the `stopwatch` resumes again and again (i.e., 30 min countdown, 5 min break, 30 min countdown, etc. until manual reset or stop). I thought using `setInterval` inside of the `timer` function to keep calling `stopWatch` forever -- if a `breakTime` existed -- would work, but I appear to be missing something. Unfortunately, it counts down and stops dead. Where am I going wrong?

```
function timer(minutes) {
    let breakTime = parseInt($("#breakLength").html());
    if (breakTime === 0) {
        stopWatch(minutes);
    } else {
        setInterval(stopWatch(minutes), breakTime*60000);
    }
}

function stopWatch (minutes) {
    let initialize = new Date();
    let deadLine = new Date(initialize.getTime() + minutes*60000);

    intervalHandle = setInterval(function() {
        let timeSet = Date.parse(deadLine) - Date.parse(new Date());
        if (timeSet > 0) {
            let total_seconds = (timeSet) / 1000;

            let hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / 3600);
            total_seconds = total_seconds % 3600;

            let minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60);
            total_seconds = total_seconds % 60;

            let seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds);

            // display time as HH:MM:SS
            hours = pretty_time_string(hours);
            minutes = pretty_time_string(minutes);
            seconds = pretty_time_string(seconds);
            let currentTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            timeRemaining = timeSet;
            console.log(currentTimeString);
            $("#displayHours").html(hours);
            $("#displayMins").html(minutes);
            $("#displaySecs").html(seconds);
        } else {
            stopTimer(intervalHandle);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: what's the stopTimer function?

Comment: If we're out of milliseconds, stop trying to do the time math and end the countdown. It was there before I tried handling the break functionality. After I posted this, I noticed it still lingering there, so I commented it out and it hand no effect on the problem. You may have guessed that this is my first time dealing with time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error comes from nesting setInterval functions. But someone with a better understanding of that should be able to give a better answer.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I knew that doing some kind of loop was out. I ruled out anything to do with setTimeout(), which does the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish. The appropriate arguments are being passed to the right spots (it seems), but that's an excellent conjecture on which I will follow-up.

Comment: Thanks - maybe if you can get some good info on setInterval it would be helpful. From what i remember it does some stuff on the document that aren't intuitively notable when you don't know the backstage of it. But i don't recall what.

Comment: Hi Ryan! First of all, when you hit timeset <= 0 you should get the error, because there's no stopTimer function in js, it is clearInterval actually.

Comment: @EugeneOlisevich Yeah, I got over zealous in making my own functions. I had stupidly embedded theirs in mine and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, i think you never get the timer execution again just because your forget to launch it after timer completes. 
I've refactor your version a little bit, so you can get the way you should change your code.
Hope this behaviour is what you want by default.

```js
let tickHandler;
let breakHandler;

function kill() {
  clearInterval(tickHandler);
  clearTimeout(breakHandler);
}

function timer(minutes) {
  let breakTime = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#breakTime').value, 10) * 60000;

  startWatch(minutes, breakTime);
}

function display(deadLine) {
  let displayDate = new Date(deadLine);
  let hrs = displayDate.getUTCHours().toString();
  let min = displayDate.getUTCMinutes().toString();
  let sec = displayDate.getUTCSeconds().toString();

  document.querySelector("#watch").value = hrs.padStart(2, '0') + ' : ' + min.padStart(2, '0') + " : " + sec.padStart(2, '0');
}

function startWatch(minutes, breakTime) {
  breakHandler = setTimeout(function() {
    let initialize = new Date(0);
    let deadLine = new Date(minutes * 60000);
    let currDate = Date.now();

    display(deadLine);

    tickHandler = setInterval(function() {
      let timePass = Date.now() - currDate;
      deadLine = deadLine - timePass;

      if (deadLine > 0) {
        let displayDate = new Date(deadLine);

        display(displayDate);
        currDate = Date.now();
      } else {
        clearInterval(tickHandler);
        startWatch(minutes, breakTime);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, breakTime);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label>BreakTime</label>
  <input id="breakTime" value="0" />
  <br/>
  <button onclick="timer(1)">Start Timer</button>
  <button onclick="kill()">Stop Timer</button>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <label>Left:</label><input id="watch" readonly="true" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow! This is almost exactly it. My timer goes countdown-break-countdown-break etc. You got the break followed by the restart, which was the part I needed, along with notes on how to refactor my code. Sincerely appreciate the work you did here.